# SQL SERVER, use patIndex to find position of a character to the left of another character position

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have used `patindex` to find a character position in my nvarchar

```
declare @pmReportText nvarchar(max)
set @pmReportText = 'lots and lots of text;

declare @emptyTag int
select @emptytag = patindex('%></%',@pmReportText) +1
```

from that point (value in `@emptyTag`) I need to find the first match to the left. (`patindex('>%<',@pmReportText)`)

I need the position I get to relate to the current nvarchar (`@pmReportText`) so I don't think using something like

```
declare @leftOfTag nvarchar(max)
    select @leftOfTag = rtrim(left(@pmReportText, @emptytag-1))
    select @leftOfTag = reverse(@leftOfTag)

    declare @startEmptyTag int
    select @startEmptyTag = patindex('>%<',@leftOfTag)
```

will work because the position will not relate to the original varchar `@pmReport`

Is what I am trying to do possible? If so how would I go about doing it?

***Edit:*** below is a snippet of data from the nvarchar i am working with,
[image]

Green is the position I am at (@emptyTag), I want to get the position in red.

Comment: A small sample data segment and desired results would be helpful

Comment: I am working with a bug that inserted a lot of html into a  radEditor created report, (more than 128 levels so I can't use xml) I will edit to include a snippet because what I am trying to work with is close to unreadable and over 45000 characters long,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you've started with will lead to a solution.

Your `@startEmptyTag` will contain the location of the search-character in the REVERSE of the substring, as you know.

Consider then, that this is the equivalent to the distance (number of characters) that the search-character is to the Left of the `@emptyTag` in the original string.

Now you just have to subtract the distance from the location of the `@emptyTag` and you've got the location of your search-character.   You will have to do some math with the length of the "search-character" if it is more than one character, of course.